# if pt100 thermal sensor 200 meter is far from plc ....does plc read the temperature correctly?

Tags: plc

if **pt100** thermal sensor`200` meters is far from plc. does plc read the temperature correctly ?
I connected **k** type before and it read wrongly

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy depends on few factors for RTDs.

If you use a 3-wire scheme, then it should be more or less correct. In cases of long distances I recommend to use **PT1000** 4-wire scheme. This will compensate for resistances on both the supply and measurement side.

If you have 2-wire scheme, than any resistance from the cable run will impact the accuracy of your measurement, You may need to connect perform a calibration depending on your requirements.

To calibrate: Install resistor magazine on the end of the wire, set it 100Ohm, read data and use it for correction. In other words with correction and 100Ohm magazine, PLC should show 0.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the correct compensation cable for the Type **K** thermocouple?
Thermocouples cannot be connected with normal copper wires, they need special specific cable.

If the sensor cable is not physically separated from power cables neither with thermocouple nor with PT100 it will work fine. At least 0.5m separation